# Некорректная работа с условиями

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Программа должна узнавать на определённую дату забронирована квартира или нет, если нет, то бронируем, если да, то вывести сообщение, что она забронирована. Как работает моя программа:

Первый прогон: делаем Post-запрос с информацией, что хотим забронировать на `2020-03-12` по `2020-03-19`. Программа сохраняет. Если сделаем ещё один точно такой же запрос, то программа снова сохраняет информацию.

Второй прогон: делаем Post-запрос с информацией, что хотим забронировать на `2020-03-12` по `2020-03-19`. Программа пишет, что квартира уже занята. Делаем новый Post-запрос, что хотим забронировать на `2020-04-12` по `2020-04-19`, программа сохраняет информацию. Если сделаем ещё один точно такой же запрос, то программа снова сохранит.

Как реализован запрос в БД: ищем в БД `Contract` по `id House` и `end_date` позже, чем `start_date` у нового `Contract`. Таким образом можно будет найти либо действующий `Contract`, либо отсутствующий, в случае если отсутствует, то можно создать новый.

Как хотел сделать в контроллере проверку: если у нас ничего не вернул запрос, то мы можем сохранить в базу данных новый контракт, в ином случае заходим в условие и сохраняем.

В чём проблема: как мне правильно выстроить условие, что корректно сохранялись данные? Потому что повторного сохранения не должно быть на одну и ту же дату.

Контроллер:

```
@PostMapping("/rent")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:write')")
public String homeRent(@RequestBody ContractDto contractDto) {
    List<Contract> con = contractService.findContractByHouseIdAndEndDateAfter(contractDto.getHouseId(), contractDto.getEndDate());
    if(con.isEmpty()) {
        Contract contract = new Contract();
        contract.setHouse(houseService.findById(contractDto.getHouseId()));
        contract.setUser(userService.findById(contractDto.getTenantId()));
        contract.setStartDate(contractDto.getStartDate());
        contract.setEndDate(contractDto.getEndDate());
        contractService.save(contract);
        return "Квартира забронирована";
    }
    return "Квартира занята";
}
```

Репо

```
@Repository
public interface ContractRepository extends JpaRepository<Contract, Long> {
    List<Contract> findContractByHouseIdAndEndDateAfter(Long houseId, LocalDate from);
}
```

Comment: Делайте select из БД за этот день, возвращайте Optional<Contract>, его удобно проверять на null или реальный объект. Если возвращается null, значит создается новый контракт. Для фильтрации в БД по дням есть функция postgres - date_trunc()

Comment: я добавил репо, т.е. мой вариант не является корректным? Можете продемонстрировать какой-нибудь рабочий вариант?

Comment: в принципе надо делать запрос который покажет какие дни свободны и выводить их в календаре на фронте. Пусть заказчик выбирает.

Comment: @AlekseiGaile попробовал в своём коде поменять возвращаемый параметр на Optional - не помогло, всё точно также такая же проблема. Проверял вот так: if(!con.isPresent())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Query(value = "select * from contract 
WHERE id = :houseId
  and visit_date > :startDate
  and visit_date < cast(:endDay as date) + interval '1' day", nativeQuery = true)
List<Contract> findAllByDate(@Param("houseId") Long houseId, @Param("startDate") LocalDate startDate, @Param("endDay") LocalDate endDay);
```

Предположу, что в данной реализации приложения надо смотреть промежуток дат на который клиент хочет зарезервировать номер. Если данный запрос что то возвращает, то запрос не должен сохранять контракт в БД, если он возвращает null, тогда создаем новый контракт.

Comment: кажется, что немного напутали, в @param (первом) нужно написать startDay, а то два end получается. Сейчас протестирую. У меня вопрос, а как программа понимает про какую квартиру тут идёт речь? Кажется, что этот момент упустили, потому что у нас же много квартир в базе, а не одна

Comment: Ещё он даже запустить не даёт, такую ошибку выдаёт, хотя запрос в целом верно написан, должен ведь запускаться: `Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List task.homerent.repository.ContractRepository.findAllByDate(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate) but parameter 'Optional[startDay]' not found in annotated query 'select * from contract WHERE visit_date > :startDate and visit_date < cast(:endDay as date) + interval '1' day'!`

Comment: Подправил. Посмотрите на ваш объект - LocalDate или Date у вас прописан. Может  по этому проблема.

Comment: Я просто использую LocalDate, Date - это ведь уже старая версия

Comment: Исправил запрос.

Comment: Всё работает точно также, как и у меня тогда, т.е. неправильно и если на один и тот же адрес постоянно посылаю запрос, то он всегда бронирует квартиру, но это при условии, что проверяю не на null, а на size == 0. Если на null, то он всегда пишет, что квартира занята, запрос выглядит как у вас, но вместо двух visit_date у меня стоит start_date - это название из таблицы, начало арендного дня.

Comment: @Blacit тогда дебажить надо, смотреть что возвращает запрос и почему так происходит.

Comment: Когда на эту дату нет ничего, то он возвращает size = 0, сохраняет запись, если сразу ещё один запрос сделать, то размер всё равно равен 0. Как это вообще возможно?

Comment: @Blacit  а в БД записи появляются?

Comment: Он всегда показывает размер 0. Смотрю, записей на одну и ту же дату уже больше 3, а он всё равно показывает, что 0.

Comment: @Blacit значит какая то проблема с запросом, поиграйте напрямую с запросом к БД, без кода.

Comment: Попытался сделать запросы, что-то не так с ним, не возвращает ничего. Вот такой запрос делал `select * from contract 
WHERE id = 6
  and start_date > cast('2020-03-12' as date)
  and start_date < cast('2020-03-19' as date) + interval '1' day`

Comment: @Blacit значит надо смотреть что вообще есть в БД и записывается ли туда что нибудь

Comment: Вот проблема в том, что в БД всё пишется, когда делаю запрос через postman, но ничего не возвращается, мне кажется, что запрос некорректный

Comment: id = 6 есть такой?

Comment: Когда я только запускаю базу с liquibase, то заполняется таблица контракт до 5 включительно. Да, id = 6 есть в базе, я перед запросом добавил и проверил

Comment: select * from contract  WHERE id = 6 - такой запрос что то вернет?

Comment: Да, вернул запись из контракта. Начало аренды, конец, id_tenant, id_house и просто id

Comment: а какая дата начала и конца аренды?

Comment: Я такие вбил: 2020-03-19 - end_date 2020-03-12- start_date. id_house = 6, id_tenant = 6

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113745/discussion-on-answer-by-alekseigaile----).